# filling in blank cells with cells above

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that looks like this:

```
BusABC     Florida     Rush Street     15
blank      blank       Landon Street   29
blank      blank       Naples Street   34
Bus123     Georgia     Rush Street     15
blank      blank       Marietta Street 29234
blank      blank       Duluth Street   321
blank      blank       Augusta Avenue  12
```

I want to use code to have a result where the blanks match the data above. So A2, A3 would have "BusABC" and B2, B3 would have "Florida."

Then A5, A6, and A7 would have "Bus123" and B5, B6, and B7 would have "Georgia."

I need to not use specific cell numbers as I have thousands of group set ups like this and my code cannot reference a specific cell.

Additionally, there may be blank cells in columns C and D (in my example) and I need those to stay blank

I tried this (below)...... I end up with cells that have 0s and #N/A

```
On Error Resume Next
With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
  .Value = .Value
End With
```

I have also tried this and nothing happens:

```
Sub split()
    Dim columnValues  As Range, i As Long

    Set columnValues = Selection

    For i = 1 To columnValues.Rows.Count
        If columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = columnValues.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling out the `.value = .Value` from the `SpecialCells()` makes it work.

```
With Selection
    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    End With
  .Value = .Value
End With
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: I end up with #REF! in all of the empty cells.  Any blank cells in columns other than A and B need to remain blank.

Comment: Then only choose the cells in the columns you want.  You stated you do not want to use ranges.  So only choose the cells on which you want to run the code.  The only way you will end up with #Ref is if you choose the first row and it is empty.  Again only choose those areas that need the values.  You need to start with the first actual value.  We are not here to give you the code or rewrite your code to do more than it does, but to help overcome a specific problem.

Comment: Just an FYI, you show your thanks by marking it as correct clicking the check mark by the answer.  This marks the answer as the correct answer and removes the question from the unanswered queue.  i am glad you were able to get an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I generally object to using VBA to write formulas. Therefore I created a solution which writes the results instead. Unfortunately, I appear to be late in posting. You already accepted an answer. However, since I wrote the code I might as well share it. Here it is.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillMissing()
    ' 04 Jan 2018

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Service As Variant
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last row
    Dim R As Long                               ' row counter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Rl = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
        For R = 2 To Rl                         ' start in row 2
            Set Rng = Range(.Cells(R, "A"), .Cells(R, "B"))
            With Rng
                If Application.CountA(Rng) Then
                    Service = .Value
                Else
                    .Value = Service
                End If
            End With
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```